JS console logging using styles (%c) adds unintended line breaks
I'm working on some debugging logging prettification and I noticed that when you do longer chunks of styled text, the console tends to add line breaks. I wonder if I can prevent this behavior. Maybe there's something in the styles that could prevent it elegantly?
Here's an example:
const cssHeadField = `border-bottom: 1px solid grey;font-family: 'Courier New',monospace;font-weight: 600;font-size: 1.2em;background-color: Orange; color: black`;
const cssError = `background-color: Red; color: black`;

console.log(`no formatting at all %c and now head field kicks in and now it stops: %c and now a bunch of text that has no formatting, oop! %can error here%c some more text with no for... %coh, another error!%c`, cssHeadField, "", cssError, "", cssError, "")
console.log(`no formatting at all %c and now head field kicks in and now it stops: %c and now a bunch of text that has no formatting, oop! %can error here, maybe a longer error description too something that would be multiline or something right?%c some more text with no for... %coh, another error! This one is supposed to be long too just to test it out I guess%c`, cssHeadField, "", cssError, "", cssError, "");



"I wonder if I can prevent this behaviour" - yes: use Firefox  :)

Wow. Yes, I need it to be exactly as in FF. Switching to FF is not a solution though. I'm having it in a chrome extension. Once chrome blocks adblockers for good with its deceptive mv3 changes, I will certainly switch to FF and move my extension to FF too, but before that, I wouldn't mind a solution for Chrome.

Report the bug? Unless the good people at google don't consider it a bug of course.

Reported, but I'd reported a bunch of similar bugs and never heard back from them. And the bugs are still there. Like when you filter the console by the file name, it works, but it doesn't show you any new logs, unlike text-based filtering. Or like you can't use chrome:// urls in a href, but you can do it with a click listener and then chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://... I doubt they pay much attention to the bug reports. I typically use Chrome -> Help -> Report an Issue for that, but to no avail.
